# Magento 2, how to do performance testing in site?

Tags: magento2, performance

### Performance test in Magento 2 using CLI

In magento 2, how to do performance testing for core module of magento application?

Comment: Did you find any way to check magento 2 performance except below ans?

Comment: hmmm atyre koi j ext or tutorial maltu j nathi.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this magento devdocs documentation for more details on performance testing.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html

Thanks

Comment: I didn't find an information about how to RUN tests.